# Kubernetes egress static IP. the most elegant and working solution?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

Can someone tell me how you solved this problem in the most optimal and elegant way?
There is a Kubernetes cluster with some deployments, some clients need to add our IPs to their whitelist so that applications can do requests.
With the scalability of the cluster, it is necessary to give new IPs from our new nodes for whitelisting to clients or deploy applications on the same nodes.

The solution is not optimal, so you need fix IPs. Make them either static or so that they go out through one gateway.

Kubernetes installation is standard with network provider Flannel. This provider does not have such feature.

1. Such feature has for example calico. https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/networking/use-specific-ip
2. I also found this project: https://github.com/nirmata/kube-static-egress-ip - has anyone used it?

What are your suggestions?

If it helps, then our hosting is on Hetzner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution could probably be Antrea https://antrea.io/docs/v1.3.0/docs/egress/ the CNI used for ex. by VMWare Tanzu among others.
With Antrea you could define an EgressIPPool and the CNI would automatically manage the pool providing HA capabilities between Kubernetes nodes. You set a label on those pods which require to use a static outgoing address and you are done.

Calico has a similar feature but the Egress Gateway is a paid option, so you are limited to use an IPPool and to assign IP blocks to K8s nodes and to label certain pods to make them use those IP's. As you have guessed in a large cluster environment these ip pools may run out very quickly.
Also I had L2 routing problems (pods couldn't be reached from addresses within the same VLAN) but that's probably some configuration fault on my part.

I also tried to install Cillium and it's really advanced and efficient but for the Egress Gateway it supports a single IP on a node only (which must be manually configured on the node's interface) with no HA capabilities.

If no CNI migration is possible, your last resource

Comment: Hi. I wrote you a big answer. But moronic moderators and bots blocked my post with the justification that this is not a discussion club.
What about Service Mesh? I have now installed Istio. I will try to set up Egress Gateway. There's a whole section for just that. https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/ Did you try it?

Comment: Hi, no I didn't that's an alternative for sure, but I'm not fond of the sidecar container you need for istio, it seems like an overkill to me. In my case Antrea with egress objects seems to work fine!

Comment: @LucaDeRugeriis your answer seems to be truncated.